# Generate a YouTube playlist (or list of links) from a list of track names

Tags: windows, youtube

I want to input a list of "Artist - Title" and automatically generate a YT playlist or list of YT links.

ChatGPT can't do this as it doesn't respond with links, maybe another chatbot? It did give this suggestion to achieve this tool:

https://chat.openai.com/share/e8629f53-aa9c-4581-9a6a-75bc88fae9b8

Edit: Bing chatbot can give a list of links: https://imgur.com/a/pzfazYJ
The ultimate result would be directly generating a YT playlist from a list of title.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp). For example:

```
yt-dlp "ytsearch:Rammstein Ohne Dich" --skip-download --print webpage_url
```

That looks for the best match and outputs the URL like this:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIPc1cfS-oQ

You can easily loop through e.g. text file with `Artist - Title` lines in PowerShell to batch output links for everything, e.g.:

```
Get-Content songs.txt | % { yt-dlp "ytsearch:$_" --skip-download --no-warnings --print webpage_url }
```

See:

- [output templates](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#output-template)
- [supported sites/searches](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/blob/7cccab79e7d00ed965b48b8cefce1da8a0513409/supportedsites.md?plain=1#L1804)

for more options.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, since I am not a coder it is a challenge for me. 

I have found an alternative, bing chat:

https://imgur.com/a/pzfazYJ

Comment: You really don't need to be a programmer to paste a command to PowerShell window. But AI could work too indeed, with a bit lower reliability.